# Probe probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry

Tags: metrics, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating, probe

Folks,

I'm setup a Grafana Dashboard...

How setup the metric on Grafana using the probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry to show the values in year,month, days ?

Thanks,
Sergio

I tried : probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{application="Tech Support", environment="PROD"} - time()
The result is: 1.11 year